# python - are connections sockets?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, networking

have not programmed in python much and I am confused on the types for a socket and a connection.I have this so far.

```
connectionList = []
incomingSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
incomingSock.bind(('127.0.0.1', args.tcpPort))
outgoingSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
outgoingSock.connect((args.serverOverIp,args.serverOverPort))
connectionList.append(outgoingSock)
while 1:
    connection, address = self.sock.accept()
    connectionList.append(connection)
    connectionListener(connection,address)
```

My question is "are connections returned by socket.accept sockets aswell? Can I add them to the same list as the socket it spawned from?"

Comment: The return value of `accept()` is a socket, not a connection.

Answer (score 0):

> ... are connections returned by socket.accept sockets as well

From [the documentation of accept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept):

> ... The return value is a pair (conn, address) where **conn is a new socket object usable to send and receive data on the connection** ...

In other words, it is a socket as well.

> Can I add them to the same list as the socket it spawned from ...

There is no indication in your question of what you use this list for. So while you can add it to the list it is unclear if this makes sense in the context of the rest of your code (the one not shown, where you make use of this list).

Comment: I was going to loop over it and call send like so. `i = 0
                    while i < len(connectionList):
                        currConnection = connectionList[i]
                        currConnection.send(senderName+' sendto '+ recieverName +' '+messageSplit[2])
                        i+=1` edit:sorry about the formatting not sure how make new line in a comment

Comment: @PeterYang: yes, you can do it for this.